# Libby Pipes Sending / Receiving string problems in Delphi XE

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe

I am using Russell Libby Pipes last modified in 2010. I have a TpServer sending/receiving messages with multiple TpClients.  This worked fine under Delphi7 but now in XE (recently upgraded Pipes also to 2010) a string comes through with #0 between characters  eg. '9'#0'8'#0'.  I suspect Unicode is the problem but the solution has evaded me.  Here are my Server send and Client receive routines. Any help is appreciated.

```
procedure TfrmServer.CommSend(aStr: String);
begin  // Broadcast message; Messages are kept as short as possible
   editSend.Text := aStr;
   try
      Size := editSend.GetTextBuf(Buffer, 250);            // Put text into buffer
      PipeServer.Broadcast(Buffer^, Size*2);                 // Send the message to the Clients
      Application.ProcessMessages;
   except
   end;
end;

PROCEDURE TfrmClient.PipeMessage(Sender: TObject; Pipe: Cardinal; Stream: TStream);
VAR  // Incoming message
   xInStream: TStringStream;
   xSize: Integer;
BEGIN // Message received from network
   xInStream := TStringStream.Create('');
   TRY
      xSize := Stream.Size;
      xInStream.CopyFrom(Stream, xSize);                   // Copy stream to local variable
      editRcvd.Text := xInStream.DataString;

      frmOptions.NetMessage(editRcvd.Text);
   EXCEPT
      ShowMessage('DMS Client - Message Error: ' + editRcvd.Text); // Debug
   END;

   xInStream.Free;                                         // Erases any contents
END;
```

Comment: I see you use String on the server side and AnsiString on the client side. This is not good, change your code so that the string types match on both sides.

Comment: Sorry!!  That was part of some debugging not in the still not working app.

Comment: If you want everything like in D7, make sure you cast to AnsiString on server and client side. Maybe the library is not unicode compatible?

Comment: I blogged about Russell code which I updated for Delphi XE3. http://francois-piette.blogspot.be/2013/04/inter-process-communication-using-pipes.html